# How do I access the other part of the hard drive in Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, hard-drive

I spun up a EC2 large instance:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  2.5G  5.1G  33% /
none                  7.4G  112K  7.4G   1% /dev
none                  7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
none                  7.4G   40K  7.4G   1% /var/run
none                  7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /var/lock
/dev/xvdb             414G  199M  393G   1% /mnt
```

But all my usage is going to xvda1.

How do I start using xvdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting stuff in `/mnt` directory should work just fine. Are you doing that?

Sorry to put this in the answer (no enough rep to comment.): I do not think this is a EC2 specific question. Maybe you should leave out EC2 in the title. If I am wrong, please tag with "amazon-ec2".